# This is possible?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

It's possible make the following xml code programmatically? and How?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_item_label"
        style="@style/TextWithWhiteShadow"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_light_gray_search_input"
        android:textSize="@dimen/home_item_text_size">

        <requestFocus
           android:duplicateParentState="true"
           android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    </TextView>
```

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html you have all the related methods corresponding to their xml attributes.

Comment: Use the page linked by @ZouZou and ask more specific questions if something is unclear on the way.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Combined with the link to the docs above, other parts of the docs, and the new [search feature SO implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=programmatically+make+textview+%5Bandroid%5D) you should be able to at least make an attempt.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for reply, i'm checking right now the links you posted, but... what about the <requestFocus /> tag? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZouZou suggested, go to [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Here you can search for set methods that relate to xml attribute. For example: `android:maxlines` attribute, there is `setMaxLines(int maxlines)` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29). You will find every method corresponding to XML attribute.
Then all you have to do is

```
TextView tv=new TextView(getContext());
tv.setMaxLines(1);
....
```

Good luck!